# Can't import Quandl

Tags: python, anaconda

I'm running python 3.6 in Anaconda. I've run pip install quandl in command prompt and now i'm trying to import Quandl, it gives me this error:

import Quandl
Traceback (most recent call last):

File "", line 1, in 
    import Quandl

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'Quandl'

I've checked the Anaconda program file and the quandl file is there. Any idea why it can't see the quandl file.

Comment: try importing quandl in lowercase

Comment: Have a feeling that somewhere along the way it changed to `quandl` (lowercase 'q') but tutorials and documentation can use a mix

Comment: Agree. It should be lowercase "quandl ". Please run "conda list" to check the name of the package.

Answer (score 0):

try lowercasing quandl (import quandl), if that doesn't work try reinstalling quandl as a lowercase and then doing import quandl

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and fixed it by using lowercase quandl. That solved my issue.